# Python dictionary assignment during list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary of permissions as such:

```
{'READ': True,  'WRITE': None, 'DELETE': False}
```

The actual dictionary has more keys, but this suffices for the example. I would like to iterate over the dictionary and change any values of `None` to `False`. This can be done easily with a for loop, but I'm wondering if there's an idiomatic way to do it with a list comprehension. If it was an object instead of a dictionary I would just do:

```
[setattr(k, v, False) for k, v in object if v is None]
```

(or similar), but I'm not sure how to do it like that without using `dict.__setitem__`

This isn't super important to solve my problem, but I'm just wondering if there's a more concise way to do it

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> dct = {'READ': True,  'WRITE': None, 'DELETE': False}
>>> dct = {k:v if v is not None else False for k,v in dct.items()}
>>> dct
{'READ': True, 'WRITE': False, 'DELETE': False}
>>>
```

Note: If you are on Python 2.x, you should use [`dict.iteritems`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) instead of `dict.items`.  Doing so will improve efficiency since the former returns an iterator where as the later returns a list.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a list comprehension for the side effects; no point in producing a list of `None` values here.

Instead, use a dict comprehension:

```
{k: False if v is None else v for k, v in object.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Why not just use a loop instead of creating a new dict?

Comment: @KDawG I understand, but it looks like the OP is trying to be "idiomatic" when it's not necessary.

Comment: @arshajii: Since you have to test *all keys* anyway, a dict comprehension *is* idiomatic.

Comment: Yes, I think idiomatic was the wrong word. What I was trying to get at was: would it not be preferable though to modify the dict in-place (i.e. using a simple loop)?

Comment: That depends on how many values are being replaced here, and what the goal is. Performance or readability? Feeling butch because you are using advanced Python syntax (yes, that's apparently a reason to use dict comprehensions). I agree that a simple loop will probably perform better.